# Bootstrap form builder

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, formbuilder

I'm using this [form builder](http://minikomi.github.io/Bootstrap-Form-Builder/), but it's a problem with id's (and names) of the elements - if I use two (or more) same elements - all of those elements will have the same id (and name). Does anyone know how to change the code to have different id's (and names)? For example by two textinputs - first element textinput1, second element textimput2.

Thx and sorry for my English :)

Answer (score 0):

After dropping your element in your form, just click on the dropped element to change id, name, etc...

Comment: Hi, I know that's possible. But I want it automatically.